# How to get explicit Context instance to get access to SQLite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-context, sqliteopenhelper

I am storing data into SQLite database using a Broadcast receiver which has its Context.
Now, I am looking into fetching data from the same database, but I am unable to get the same as I don't have the Context instance while creating the object of the class AppDataSQLHelper which contains code to access the SOLite database.

```
public AppDataSQLHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Links referred to work on SQLite database:
https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: you will need to send class name as context

Comment: *I don't have the Context instance while creating the object of the class AppDataSQLHelper* then you can't create it ... but obviously this is proly not true - you should have some context object there (blind guess as we don't know where you wana do this)

Comment: I didn't understand your question clearly. Use static variable to store context. or _I am storing data into SQLite database using a Broadcast receiver which has its Context_  : Make db object as static

Comment: "I don't have the Context instance" -- every entry point into your app involves a `Context`. Your `Activity` is a `Context`. Your `Service` is a `Context`. Your `ContentProvider` can call `getContext()`. And so on.